# FontAwesomeSwiftKit enum from String

Tags: swift, enums, font-awesome

I am using FontAwesomeKit_Swift to display FontAwesome images in my storyboard. My web service contains the font-awesome name such as fa-beer

My swift code is the following:

```
faBadge.image = UIImage(awesomeType: .fa_beer, size: 20.0, color: UIColor.blue)
```

However, the awesomeType is tied to an enum.  How can I make this convert my string of "fa-beer" to the .fa_beer enum?

Answer (score 0):

The type of FontAwesomeType is unichar (UInt16)

```
public enum FontAwesomeType: unichar { ...
```

so you should not have "fa_beer" as a string on the server. you may have raw value of .fa_beer on the server and at the time of receiving, you may parse it to unichar and then convert it to FontAwesomeType. like this;

```
let faBeerValue:Int = Int(FontAwesomeType.fa_beer.rawValue) // Keep this value on the server

let faBeer:FontAwesomeType? = FontAwesomeType(rawValue: unichar(faBeerValue)); // After receiving the value convert it.
```

Comment: I was trying to reuse an existing web service that stored the font awesome names as a string.  I was hoping to not have to modify the web service.